# Twitter oauth skip the Allow connection screen for existing users

Tags: oauth, twitter

I have successfully let users to connect to my web application with twitter oauth. And I can insert user information after they logged in.

My problem with is that existing users are always redirected to the Allow/Deny application screen on twitter each time they click on sign in with twitter.

How can I skip this step for my existing users so they don't have to click on allow every time they sign in?

I am using this library: http://www.haughin.com/code/twitter/

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is done with the [Sign in with Twitter flow](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/sign_in_with_twitter). Instead of sending users to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/**authorize**?oauth_token=xyz send them to https://api.twitter.com/oauth/**authenticate**?oauth_token=xyz. In this case if the user has previously authorized your app and are already authenticated with twitter.com they will automatically be redirected back to your app without being prompted to allow/deny access.

Answer (score -1):

When a user authorizes your application to use their Twitter account, Twitter gives you two tokens:  OAuthToken and OAuthTokenSecret.

Stores these tokens in a cookie, or a settings file, or whatever.

Then, the next time you need to make a request to Twitter on behalf of this user, you use those tokens.

Comment: store oauthtokensecret in a cookie? terrible advice

Comment: Yes, I was being somewhat generic and answering the question in the spirit in which it was asked rather than addressing the minutiae of how to specifically store it.